# Sum field(s) from one table in another table, summing from 3 different tables

Tags: database, ms-access

I have an Access database with customer IDs. Each customer can have multiple orders and each order can be of a different type. I have three separate tables (Online, In-store, Payment Plan) for each order type with various amounts from each order, all are related to a customer ID. In one of the tables, there are two types of order types that amounts must be maintained separately withing the same table. **I want to sum each order type in another table called Totals.** I can successfully create a query to get the sums for each type based on the customer ID but I am not sure how to pull those values in my Totals table. The scenario below is repeated for multiple customers and each type is its own table---the payment plans are in a table together. I have historical data so I am limited to how I can manipulate as far as merging fields and what not.

***Customer ID#: 1***

Order Type: Online
Online Amount: $20.00

Order Type: Online
Online Amount: $40.00

**Sum of Online Amount: $60.00**

Order Type: In-store
Online Amount: $35.00

Order Type: In-store
Online Amount: $60.00

**Sum of In-Store Amount: $95.00**

Order Type: Payment Plan
Payment Plan 1 Amount: $30.00

Payment Plan 1 Amount: $23.00

**Sum of Payment Plan 1 Amount: $53.00**

Order Type: Payment Plan 2
Payment Plan 2 Amount: $35.00

Payment Plan 2 Amount: $30.00

**Sum of Payment Plan 2 Amount: $65.00**

In my Totals table I have a field for each type that sums the amount spent by each customer ID and then a field where all of their order types are summed into one overall total field.

I am learning as I go so any help/example is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having separate tables for your different order types doesn't help.  For a database it would be better to have a single table for all sales with a sale_type field.

You don't describe exactly what your tables look like, so I've had to make a couple of assumptions.  If your tables contain an `OrderType` field then you can create a Union query to join all your sales together:

```
SELECT                CustomerID
                    , OrderType
                    , Amount
FROM                Online

UNION ALL SELECT    CustomerID
                    , OrderType
                    , Amount
FROM                [In-Store]

UNION ALL SELECT      CustomerID
                    , OrderType
                    , Amount
FROM                [Payment Plan]
```

If you don't have an `OrderType` you can hard-code the values into the query:

```
SELECT                CustomerID
                    , "Online" AS OrderType
                    , Amount
FROM                Online

UNION ALL SELECT    CustomerID
                    , "In-Store"
                    , Amount
FROM                [In-Store]

UNION ALL SELECT      CustomerID
                    , "Payment Plan"
                    , Amount
FROM                [Payment Plan]
```

**Note** - The field name is declared for the `OrderType` in the first `Select` block.  You could do it in each block, but Access only looks at the first.

Like all queries, the results come in table form and can be treated as such.  So now we need to list the `CustomerName` (I'm assuming you have a `Customers` table), the `OrderType` and the sum of the amount for that `Customer` & `OrderType`.

```
SELECT        CustomerName
            , OrderType
            , SUM(Amount)
FROM        Customers INNER JOIN 
                (
                    SELECT                CustomerID
                                        , OrderType
                                        , Amount
                    FROM                Online

                    UNION ALL SELECT      CustomerID
                                        , OrderType
                                        , Amount
                    FROM                [In-Store]

                    UNION ALL SELECT      CustomerID
                                        , OrderType
                                        , Amount
                    FROM                [Payment Plan]
                ) T1 ON Customers.CustomerID = T1.CustomerID
GROUP BY    CustomerName
            , OrderType
```

All sales in your three tables will have a customer within the customers table so we can use an `INNER JOIN` to return only records where the value appears in both tables (Customers table & result of query table).
The `UNION QUERY` is wrapped in brackets and given the name `T1`and joined to the `Customers` table on the `CustomerID` field.
We group all fields that aren't part of an aggregate function, so group on `CustomerName` and `OrderType` and sum the `Amount` field.

This is all you really need to do - let the query run each time you want the totals to get the most up to date values.  There's shouldn't be a need to push the results to a `Totals` table as that will be out of date as soon as you make a new sale (or someone returns something).

If you really want to `INSERT` these figures into a `Total` table just add a first line to the SQL:

```
INSERT INTO Total (CustomerName, OrderType, Amount)
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for the detailed explanation and for all of the code, this is fantastic. Your assumptions were correct. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dirty workaround, though I think there might be a more direct solution to it.

You could create an output table (I broke it down to ID, Online, InStore and Total) and use DSum functions within an UPDATE query.

```
UPDATE tbl_Totals SET
       Total_InStore = DSum("Amount", "tbl_InStore", "Customer_ID = " & Customer_ID),
       Total_Online = DSum("Amount", "tbl_Online", "Customer_ID = " & Customer_ID),
       Total = DSum("Amount", "tbl_InStore", "Customer_ID = " & Customer_ID) + DSum("Amount", "tbl_Online", "Customer_ID = " & Customer_ID)
```